# Appending String data

Tags: java, memory-management, arraylist, io, amazon-s3

Here is my code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonArrayNew.toString().getBytes());  
 Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(jsonArrayNew.toString().getBytes().length);  
 ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
 metaData.setContentLength(contentLength);  
 s3.putObject(outputBucket,outputFile,input,metaData);
```

This is how I write files into Amazon S3. However, I need to write an `ArrayList` holding `String`s to the `s3`. I can't navigate through the `ArrayList` and append its string data into a `String` and then write it to s3. Why? Because the `String` can't hold that much content. It is same to `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder`. Later stage, I am sure I have to convert this `ArrayList` into a `LinkedList` as well.

So, is there is anyway where I can `append` data into the s3 object? Just like `BufferedWriter`?

Comment: Consider writing the ArrayList object to the S3 as string by serializing.

Comment: @varra: How? `ArrayList.toString()` ?

Comment: jsonArrayNew is the content of the whole file?

Comment: @eltabo: Yes. I guess it will crash too.

Comment: not exactly what you need here, but maybe helpful in your S3 project: http://s3.jcabi.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could fit your scenario:

Maybe somewhere you can find a better class (and better tested) to do this, but as a example, here is a Reader that reads data from a String List:

```
class SReader extends Reader{
    private Iterator<String> iterator;
    private String currentLine;
    public SReader(List<String> list){
        this.iterator = list.iterator();
        if(iterator.hasNext()){
            this.currentLine = iterator.next();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if(!iterator.hasNext() && currentLine.isEmpty()){
            return -1;
        }

        char c;int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
            if(j < currentLine.length()){
                c = currentLine.charAt(j);
                j++;
            }
            else{
                if(!iterator.hasNext()){
                    return i;
                }
                j = 0;
                currentLine = iterator.next();
                c = '\n';//currentLine.charAt(j);
            }
            cbuf[off + i] = c; 
        }
        currentLine =currentLine.substring(j);                      

        return len;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
    }
}
```

You can use it in your code:

```
List<String> d = Arrays.asList("asdasdasdasdasd", "asdasdasdas", "dasdasda", "dasdasassssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
int length = 0;
for(String s : d){
    length += s.length() + 1; //I assume you want  \n after each line
}

InputStream input = new ReaderInputStream(new SReader(d));

ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
metaData.setContentLength(length);  
s3.putObject(outputBucket,outputFile,input,metaData);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Then how are you going to write data?I think you are first physically writing data to the file, and then upload it to s3.

Comment: I think you don't need to write file to your filesystem, since putObject receive a InputStream as a parameter, so you don't mind  where your data come from (a file, a string, a net connection)

Comment: If this is a `BufferedWriter`, then you can append your data into it. How can you append data into a `FileInutStream`?

Comment: You can't append data to a InputStream, you should need a InputStream that reads data for your data source (a file, a string, a connection).